# How to disconnect A2DP from UWP app for a BluetoothDevice?

Tags: windows, uwp, bluetooth, disconnect, a2dp

I have a bluetooth device connected to my windows computer. I want to disconnect the A2DP profile that the bluetooth device is connnected with the computer. How can I do that from an UWP app?

Looked for API but did not find any.

Comment: You can do it only by calling DeviceIoControl() from Win32 API. IOCTRL code can be found in bthport.sys file.

Answer (score 0):

I have talked with Bluetooth Team, currently there is **no** publicly exposed API in UWP that can be used for A2DP profile disconnect.

Comment: Hi, is there any API to connect to A2DP or HFP?

Comment: Can this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/enable-remote-audio-playback) help you?

Comment: @MARJANKHAN , I discussed with Bluetooth Team again today and can confirm, there are no public APIs available to connect and disconnect audio profiles from UWP. –

Comment: Can you please ask about dot net core desktop app? is it possible from there?

Comment: Could the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/enable-remote-audio-playback) in my last comment help you? There is now publicly available way to do so from desktop app. It would be better if you can explain your scenario and type of device you are using.

Comment: Hi Junjie, the doc is about making local machine as A2DP sink. The scenario is reverse, remote A2DP sink needs to be disconnected.

Comment: Well, I've discussed it with the Bluetooth Team, there is now publicly available way to do so.

Comment: Can you please share any reference?